# ubuntu 24.04 Звука нет

Tags: ubuntu

В наушниках есть, а динaмики не работают. Сколько не гуглил, не помогает

Comment: Проверьте динамики на другом устройстве

Comment: Что за Ubuntu 24.04?

Comment: Сделайте `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. Чекните `Software & Updates | Additional Drivers`. Погуглите про свою аудиокарту и Linux.